# Data Not Displayed in Telemertry tab

Tags: debugging, arduino, iot, esp8266, thingsboard

I am new at using thingsboard, recently I have created a device on thingsboard and trying to send data to it through mosquitto.

The device profile is set to MQTTv2 and MQTT credentials are set. the device is being shows active which means it is receiving data but data is not displayed in telemetery tab. I am unable to troubleshoot this issue. A little guidance is appreciated.

Regards
Ahmad

I have tried to change device profile and found something interesting that when device profile is set to default and credentials type is access token than data gets display but not with device profile MQTTV2 and credentail type MQTT basic.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used MQTT protocol in TBD yet, but the facts you mention maybe are related with the rulechains associated to devices profiles and the SaveTimeseries node in the rulechains.

With a Default profile, the msg of a device are managed by the root rule chain, and for sure there is a saveTimeseries node just after a MessageTypeSwitch there.

In the case of a custom device profile, you are able to select the rulechain that's going to manage the msg of that devices. So maybe there is an absent of the SaveTimeseries node in that rule chain or maybe there is no rulechain assigned to that custom device profile.

Hope being of help.